# GitHub website is stuck on a deleted version of index.html

Tags: github-pages

I have an HTML and CSS website that I would like to host on GitHub Pages.

However, I deleted the `index.html` file from GitHub and then replaced it. GitHub Pages unfortunately only shows the page that was deleted.

I tried reverting back to the original version and then modifying it in GitHub to match the new file but unfortunately GitHub Pages does not register any of the changes I've made.

Comment: there is not enough information to diagnose your problem. Any link?

Comment: how to tell which is the right version? Again, need more info,

Comment: It works now so all's well.  I updated index.html from github and let it sit for a few hours.  Thank you for your help!